# why a disabled element can be enable by end user?

Tags: asp.net

I Disable a textbox by c# code in an ASP.net Page with below code:
Textbox1.Enabled=false; 
to prevent user changing a specific value.
as you know Textbox1.Enabled=false;  in html mode will convert to disabled="disabled" css prpoerties.
but unfortunately end user can remove this css properties by Firefox Firebug and enable the textbox and press the submit button and send the changed value to server.
so what can I do?

Comment: Reject the value in the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never - ever - trust user input. Everything submitted via website form is user input. There is nothing you can do to prevent someone from submitting anything they very well please, and you should not even try.

Instead, you should check/validate those values on the server. If it's a value you just want to display to them, but not allow them to change, then just don't have your code-behind check the value at all... since you know it should not change.

If you are enabling/disabling that TextBox based on whether the user is an 'admin' or something... then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: one should also prefer to use labels for the readonly values. (These days users are getting more techy and can find more ways to break app. then before). Always validate data on the client and server side. Use best resources to meet ur need, like in ur case u can use label and make it look like readonly textbox with css.

Answer (score 0):

The same as for **any** data that you get from the browser.

- Trust it only as much as you trust the user (and a bit less then that if you don't use SSL)

  - Untrusted users might be making an attack
  - Trusted users might be making a mistake
- Check that it is sane (if whatever condition that causes the field to be disabled holds true, then check that the field isn't submitted)
- Escape any data before you use it (e.g. for SQL before inserting it into a DB and for HTML before putting it in an HTML document).